# Check the highest and lowest date in variables

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have six variables with date. I want to check what has the highest and the lowest value.

Ex.:

```
Date1: 2014-06-12 00:00:00.000
Date2: 2014-06-12 00:00:00.000
Date3: 2014-10-20 00:00:00.000
Date4: 2014-10-21 00:00:00.000
Date5: 2014-10-21 00:00:00.000
Date6: 2014-10-24 00:00:00.000
```

The output should be:

```
Highest: 2014-10-24 00:00:00.000
 Lowest: 2014-06-12 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Did you tried anything

Comment: yes, a lot of ifs inside ifs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

' Prepare data to test
Dim date1, date2, date3, date4, date5, date6

    date1=CDate("2014/06/12")
    date2=CDate("2014/06/12")
    date3=CDate("2014/10/20")
    date4=CDate("2014/10/21")
    date5=CDate("2014/10/21")
    date6=CDate("2014/10/24")

' Initialize array    
Dim aDates
    aDates = Array( date1, date2, date3, date4, date5, date6 )

' Prepare variables to store the required information    
Dim dateMin, dateMax

    dateMin = date1
    dateMax = date1

' Iterate over the array to find the max and min values    
Dim i
    For i=1 to UBound(aDates)
        If aDates(i) < dateMin Then dateMin = aDates(i)
        if aDates(i) > dateMax Then dateMax = aDates(i)
    Next 

' Output Information
    WScript.Echo "Highest: " & CStr( dateMax )
    WScript.Echo " Lowest: " & CStr( dateMin )
```

Comment: Just FYI, you can enter date literals by surrounding the date values with `#`. No need for `CDate()`. For example, `date1 = #2014/6/12#`

Answer (score 2):

Create a array with your date and sort it

```
  Dim DateArray() As DateTime = {"2014-06-12 00:00:00.000", "2014-06-12 00:00:00.000".....your dates here}
  Dim MinDate As DateTime
  Dim MaxDate As DateTime

Array.Sort(DateArray)

      MinDate = DateArray(DateArray.GetLowerBound(0))
      MaxDate = DateArray(DateArray.GetUpperBound(0))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting some sintax errors. I am using Classic ASP